# Is there a Relationship between Quantum Groups and Lie Groups?

Tags: lie-groups, abelian-groups, quantum-groups

I know that the Lie Group is all about continuous transformation groups.
I know that the quantum group denotes various kinds of noncommutative algebra with additional structure.
Transformation group is commutative group or Abelian group right?
But I need to know what is a ralationship between a Quantum Groups and a Lie Groups.
Can be Quantum Group as a Lie Group?
Also I dont know is there any Quantum Groups which is Discrete Group?
Can you show me sample?

Comment: Transformation groups are not abelian. For example, rotations and translations of the plane do not, in general, commute.

Comment: I mean Transformation Group, but not as Transformation and rotation together!  we all know that Transformation Group and rotation group Separately are Abilen Groups Separately, but Together they are not Abilen!

Comment: Why do we know what transformation group is abelian? What do you mean by transformation here?

Comment: by the word transformation I mean, only translation but not a rotation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Quantum groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_group) are **not** groups, nor are these Hopf algebras (which is what they are) directly associated to any groups (as it the case of Lie algebras).

Comment: And nor are they just algebras (which is a big part of the point of them), but Hopf-algebras.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, thanks, corrected that. I forgot that Hopf algebras aren't algebras (in the usual definition) either.

Comment: Well, they are certainly algebras (unless you happen to require your algebras to be commutative). It is just that the extra structure is rather important for this story.

Comment: I meant: Hopf algebras are algebras only in the same sense as that rings are Abelian groups; forgetting the "Hopf" in the answer was therefore confusing at least. And indeed it would be missing a major point.